# how to display all attached thumbnails of a page in the main slider

Tags: php, html, wordpress, slider

i want to display all the attached images of a page in the main slider of my home page. i have been using following code..

```
            <div class="carousel-inner">


              <?php if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>  

                      <?php
                        $images =& get_children( array (
                          'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                          'post_type' => 'attachment',
                          'post_mime_type' => 'image'
                        ));

                        if ( empty($images) ) {
                          // no attachments here
                        } else {
                              foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {?>
                                <div class="item active">
                                <img src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_src( $attachment_id, 'full' ); ?>" alt="First slide">
                                 </div>

                          <?php
                              }
                          }
                      ?>    

                <?php endwhile;else: ?>  
                <?php echo "No slider Images found" ?>
              <?php endif; ?>    


            </div>
```

But its not loading the  images . what is it that i am doing wrong . please help me out

Comment: Are you using this code on home page ?

Comment: yup i have been using this code on home page

Comment: The image are attached on home page ? or on any other page ? Is those pages are sub-pages of homepage ?

Comment: actually right now ,i have created a new page named 'slider' and images are attached to this slider page  and i have been using the code on this page and still its not working but actually i want to do this on home page

Comment: I have answered your question

Answer (score 0):

This is how im doing it

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any',
);
$attachments = get_posts($args);
foreach ($attachments as $att)
{
     $imgThumb = image_downsize($att->ID, 'slider-image');
     echo $img = '<img src="'.$imgThumb[0].'" alt="'.$att->postitle.'" />';
}
```

This is part of the code (its more complicated at its later put the image in `<li>` elements and sorts them and so on - but this should tell you how you may get images.

[image_downsize](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_downsize) is wordpress command that takes `attachment id` and its size (named or array of width and height) and then it returns the path to the image with that size (it also scales the image if needed).

Comment: i tried but its not working , used $post->ID for post_parent and $attachments = get_posts($args);
                          $count = count( $attachments );
                          echo $count;                                         and it displaying 0

Comment: I have changed (and reformated) the `$args` array - try using it now (`'post_status' => 'any', instead of => null`);

Comment: nope ,i tried but not working   i dont get why it is returning an empty array i.e $attachments although i have attached 4 images to the page

Comment: So for that i dont know why - this code works on all pages i created allowing me to set the size for the images i want (so different sizes of slider bars, different size of the thubmnail and so on...). Sorry i couldnt help you.

Comment: Awww i think i know why is that happening - can you go to your tables adn check if there is any ,,attachment'' for your parent_id? As only one thing can prohibit this query to work  -  no attachments attached to the post_parent of yours id...

Comment: yup it is having this in [caption id="attachment_214" align="alignnone" wid... in post_content

Comment: attachment_214 => 214 is the id of the attachment not of the post it's attached to... I would like to confirm that this attachment have proper parent_id set.

Comment: yup it is having id 136 which i was using for post_parent in $args

Comment: remove for now the post_parent from my code at all, and check if anything is returned (it should return ALL attachments).

Comment: then its displaying all of the images in media

Comment: Now `var_dump($att);` in the foreach loop and check if all `post_parent` are set and to what values.

Comment: ["post_parent"]=> int(198) somewhere it is 234 ,177 186 ,,

Comment: was id of `136` in the post_parent anywhere?

Comment: no buddy not even for a single image out of 36 attachments although page has only 4 attachmentss

Comment: So this is why its not working - there is NO attachment attached to the post of id 136 - and this is the post you wanted attachments from.

Comment: yup but when i do the_content() for the post it displays all the images

Answer (score 0):

You are using [wp_get_attachment_image_src()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) function wrong way.
Here is the corrected code

```
           <div class="carousel-inner">


              <?php if(have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>  

                      <?php
                        $images =& get_children( array (
                          'post_parent' => $post->ID,
                          'post_type' => 'attachment',
                          'post_mime_type' => 'image'
                        ));

                        if ( empty($images) ) {
                          // no attachments here
                        } else {
                              foreach ( $images as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
$image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full'); // returns an array
?>
                                <div class="item active">
                                <img src="<?php echo $image_attributes[0]; ?>" width="<?php echo $image_attributes[1]; ?>" height="<?php echo $image_attributes[2]; ?>">
                                 </div>

                          <?php
                              }
                          }
                      ?>    

                <?php endwhile;else: ?>  
                <?php echo "No slider Images found" ?>
              <?php endif; ?>    


            </div>
```

Comment: nope ,i tried but not working i dont get why it is returning an empty array i.e $images although i have attached 4 images to the page –

Comment: Are using this code on that page which have attached image ?

Comment: yup of course i have code on slider.php and images on page named 'slider', which using template slider

Comment: I tested this code and working fine on my case.Not sure what is the problem on your case

Comment: I think the attachments are not attached to the posts - look at my comments to my answer.

Comment: Yes $images is returning a empty array.I testing the code and its loading the images have attached to my page.So i am confused on that now

Comment: They are in the content - they are not attached to the post. They are part of the post body - thats quite different thing...

Embed image is just a html code of `<img src="...." />` into the post body.
Attached image is image that is a POST itself (of post_type = 'attachment').  You attach post but selecting them or uploading them for the given post.  That attachment have its post_parent set to the post you were uploading it for. And then you can use the code i gave you to grab them and make resizings and so on.